# From a shell script, determine if firefox has rendered a page

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, shell, command-line

I need to run firefox from a bash script to load a url

Example

firefox -url www.google.ie

The problem is I need to know when firefox has rendered the page on the browser. Does anyone know how this could be done? There doesn't seem to be anything about this in the firefox documentation.

My goal is automated tests, Basically I have a proxy type server that sits between a browser and the web, it performs optimizations on webpages before returning them to the browser (I have a good reason for doing this). Currently I just want to know how long it takes between requesting the page and loading it in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will be helpful for you, but for alternatives - Selenium (an open source testing tool, [seleniumhq.org](http://seleniumhq.org/)) has a way to interact with firefox where you can write some sorts of scripts and run them with the selenium test runner. You run a local 'selenium server' that you can then send requests to. If this is what you're trying to accomplish, all of it can be done through a shell script.

Comment: +1 this is what I was going to suggest as well. Though whether it's the right tool or not does depend on why he wants to do this.

Comment: Thanks for that, it sounds very promising.

Answer (score 1):

From a plain vanilla install, you can't. Theoretically you could write an extension which would communicate the "page loaded" event - through a file, pipe, or whatever other mechanism you'd choose.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I was thinking the same thing but it seems like too much work for what I am trying to do. I wonder are there any alternatives?

Comment: @toc777: Depends; what is your final goal? If automated tests, see @sioked's answer - Selenium is an option there. If screenshots, there's webkit2png: http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/